# Throwing away nails

Tags: halacha, superstition, disposal, nail-cutting

As discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6490/9682), one should ideally burn or bury his nails, and one who throws them is a rasha. What is the halacha regarding placing them in a trash receptacle? Is it allowed, since it won't lead to pregnant women stepping on them, and ultimately they will be buried? Or is it not acceptable, since they are not being disposed of immediately, and is similar to merely throwing them?

Comment: Note that superstitions surrounding fingernails are not unique to Jewish sources, nor are they universally agreed upon within Jewish sources.